# Apache 2.4 - Error "405 Method Not Allowed" when submitting a PUT request

Tags: php, apache

I know this argument was asked several times but, here, at March 2018 it seems far from having a definitive answer: How to enable all HTTP verbs in Apache?

Googling around and reading some answer here, I got this configuration file (just a relevant part):

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/projectdir>
    Require all granted
    Satisfy All
</Directory>

# RESTful services provided for the fake "api" directory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}"  "!=/info.php"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "/index.php?params=$1" [NC,END]
```

So to enable PUT, DELETE and other verbs I have to enable URL rewrite, that I don't need!

Moreover this conflicts with utilities like phpmyadmin and xdebug, preventing them to works properly.

So, again: Is there a method to enable the PUT and DELETE verbs in Apache 2.4 that doesn't require URL rewrite?

In my php apps these verbs are handled! But the error is rised *before* my code is reached, so it's definitively an Apache issue / misconfiguration.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is anyone knows the answer? Two days passed, but I cannot turn on the PUT method in 2.4 Apache.

Comment: @Andrei - I finally solved this issue; I use nginx. End of my problems.

Comment: Thanks for reply, It's not a solution as PHP works for me while Curl is  not.